# foreach just return 1 value Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to show a test with questions and answers. A question have 4 answers. But I just get 4 answers of a question to all questions. How can I fix it?

```
   public function xem($id){
    $quests_of_test = QuestofTest::where('id_test', $id)->get();
  
    $ids = $quests_of_test->pluck('id_quest')->all();

    $questions = Question::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

    foreach($questions as $quest){
        $answers = Answer::where('id_quest', $quest->id)->get();
    }
    
   
    return view('Test::xem', compact('questions', 'answers'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
public function xem($id){

$quests_of_test_ids = QuestofTest::where('id_test', $id)->pluck('id_quest')->toArray();
$questions = Question::query()->whereIn('id', $quests_of_test_ids)->with('answers')->get();

return view('Test::xem', compact('questions'));
}
```

in view when u iterate $question u can do $question->answer

but before u shoul do

```
public function answer()
{
     return $this->hasOne(Answer::class, 'id_which_by_related')
     //return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'id_which_by_related') in case it has many answers so u should foreach it to iterate collection of answers
}
```

Becouse your variable in foreach was been overwritten by next iteration u got last iteration data

Work on your code and dont do like that anymore pls) learn about joins and relations

Comment: It return all answers of all questions to each questions

Comment: let me fix it)))

Comment: There u go ))))

Comment: it return json not string and I just want to get **answer** in table **answers**. How can I do that?

Comment: in view u can do @foreach($question as $something) <td>$something->title</td><td>$something->answer->title</td> @endforeach

Comment: I use $question->answers->answer but it said **Property answer does not exist on this collection instance**

Comment: I got it! A question have many answer but it return 1 answer. So hasOne -> hasMany and ??

Comment: if it has many answer logically it will be hasMay but hasMany returns collection of items so you need one more foreach inside view

Comment: Its work! Thank u! And how can I add A, B, C, D for each answer?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is variable `$answers` will be re-assigned for each loop inside foreach.

You may use

```
$answers = [];
foreach($questions as $quest){
    $answers = array_merge($answers, Answer::where('id_quest', $quest->id)->get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your Relations correctloy you can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to get alle answers with the question.

```php
public function xem($id) {
    $quests_of_test = QuestofTest::where('id_test', $id)->get();
  
    $ids = $quests_of_test->pluck('id_quest')->all();

    $questions = Question::with('answers')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
   
    return view('Test::xem', compact('questions'));
}
```

Comment: A question have many answers so my Relations are hasMany and belongsTo. Your code just return 1 answer for each question.

Comment: If Question hasMany Answers and Answer belongsTo Question this code would return all assigned Answers to a Question

Comment: But it said Property ANSWER does not exist on this collection instance